# Как менять растровые изображения с помощью SVG при наведении

Tags: javascript, css, html5, svg, css-animation

Я работаю над приложением SVG, в котором  разделил растровое изображение на пять различных треугольников.
Другое растровое изображение будет заменяться при наведении на каждый треугольник.
Я пытался, но не смог добиться желаемого результата.

*Мой вопрос, как нацелить отдельные треугольники и заменять изображения src.*

[По этой ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56586446/on-hover-change-image-src-with-animation) для примера, вы можете  черпать вдохновение, когда меняете образ при наведении курсора. Это то, что я пытаюсь сделать.

```css
.overlay {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/118/1000/800');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.overlay use {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
}

.overlay use:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.vr-head-tilt {
  position: relative;
}

.big img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.overlay .vr-images1:hover~.big .default {
  opacity: 0;
}

.overlay .vr-images1:hover~.big>img:nth-child(1) {
  z-index: 5;
  opacity: 1;
}

.overlay .vr-images2:hover~.big>img:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 5;
  opacity: 1;
}

.overlay .vr-images3:hover~.big>img:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 5;
  opacity: 1;
}

.overlay .vr-images4:hover~.big>img:nth-child(4) {
  z-index: 5;
  opacity: 1;
}

.overlay .vr-images5:hover~.big>img:nth-child(5) {
  z-index: 5;
  opacity: 1;
}

.big {
  position: relative;
}

.big img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 7%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .2s .1s ease-out;
}

.big .default {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<svg class="overlay" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
            <defs>
                <clipPath id='clip-1'>
                <polygon points="0,100 100,100 0,50"/>
                </clipPath>
                <clipPath id='clip-2'>
                <polygon points="0,50 100,100 50,00 0,0"/>
                </clipPath>
                <clipPath id='clip-3'>
                <polygon points="100,100 50,00 150,0"/>
                </clipPath>
                <clipPath id='clip-4'>
                <polygon points="100,100 200,50 200,0 150,0"/>
                </clipPath>
                <clipPath id='clip-5'>
                <polygon points="100,100 200,100, 200,50"/>
                </clipPath>
                <image id="img" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
                xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/1/1000/800" />
            </defs>
            <use xlink:href="#img" class="vr-images1" clip-path="url(#clip-1)"/>
            <use xlink:href="#img" class="vr-images2" clip-path="url(#clip-2)"/>
            <use xlink:href="#img" class="vr-images3" clip-path="url(#clip-3)"/>
            <use xlink:href="#img" class="vr-images4" clip-path="url(#clip-4)"/>
            <use xlink:href="#img" class="vr-images5" clip-path="url(#clip-5)"/>
        </svg>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class='big'>
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/rxX8VMq/left.png" class='default'>
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/r77CrCC/topleft.png">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/CzRdRtp/top.png">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/L8cSs3p/topright.png">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/D1cjqfD/right.png">
</div>
```

При наведении на каждый полигон изображение должно заменяться. Я только начинаю изучать SVG, может кто-нибудь подсказать мне, как это сделать.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to change an image source on hover with SVGs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56625236/7394871) от участника  [@Husna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9004424/husna).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/56625236/7394871

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете просто использовать `javascript` и прослушивать событие `mouseenter` для ваших элементов `<use>`:

```js
const sources = [
  "rxX8VMq/left.png",
  "r77CrCC/topleft.png",
  "CzRdRtp/top.png",
  "L8cSs3p/topright.png",
  "D1cjqfD/right.png"
];
document.querySelectorAll('use[class^="vr-images"]').forEach(elem => {
  elem.addEventListener('mouseenter', updateImageSrc);
});

function updateImageSrc(evt) {
  const index = parseInt(this.classList[0].replace('vr-images', '')) || 1;
  const src = "https://i.ibb.co/" + sources[index - 1];
  document.querySelector('img').src = src;
}
```

```css
.overlay {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/118/1000/800');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.overlay use {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
}

.overlay use:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.vr-head-tilt {
  position: relative;
}

.big img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.big {
  position: relative;
}

.big img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 7%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .2s .1s ease-out;
}

.big .default {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<svg class="overlay" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id='clip-1'>
      <polygon points="0,100 100,100 0,50"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id='clip-2'>
      <polygon points="0,50 100,100 50,00 0,0"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id='clip-3'>
      <polygon points="100,100 50,00 150,0"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id='clip-4'>
      <polygon points="100,100 200,50 200,0 150,0"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id='clip-5'>
      <polygon points="100,100 200,100, 200,50"/>
    </clipPath>
    <image id="img" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
    xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/1/1000/800" />
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#img" class="vr-images1" clip-path="url(#clip-1)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#img" class="vr-images2" clip-path="url(#clip-2)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#img" class="vr-images3" clip-path="url(#clip-3)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#img" class="vr-images4" clip-path="url(#clip-4)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#img" class="vr-images5" clip-path="url(#clip-5)"/>
</svg>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class='big'>
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/rxX8VMq/left.png" class='default'>
</div>
```

Вы также можете сделать это только с помощью CSS, немного изменив структуру документа:

Вам нужно отделить каждый `overlay` полигонов, как их собственный элемент `<svg>`, чтобы вы могли ориентироваться на них, когда они наведены как `siblings` вашего контейнера с классом .big.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.background {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/118/1000/800');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.overlay use {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.overlay use:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.vr-head-tilt {
  position: relative;
}

.big img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.vr-images1:hover ~ .big img:nth-of-type(1) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.vr-images2:hover ~ .big img:nth-of-type(2) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.vr-images3:hover ~ .big img:nth-of-type(3) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.vr-images4:hover ~ .big img:nth-of-type(4) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.vr-images5:hover ~ .big img:nth-of-type(5) {
  opacity: 1;
}

svg[class*="vr-images"]:not(.vr-images1):hover ~ .big img.default {
  opacity: 0;
}

.big {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}
.big .default {
  opacity: 1;
}
.big img, .big .white-bg {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, 7%);
  transition: .2s .1s ease-out;
  background-size: cover;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.big .white-bg {
  background: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.container:not(:hover) .vr-images1{ opacity:1; }
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" style="position:aboslute;pointer-events:none">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id='clip-1'>
    <polygon points="0,100 100,100 0,50"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id='clip-2'>
    <polygon points="0,50 100,100 50,00 0,0"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id='clip-3'>
    <polygon points="100,100 50,00 150,0"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id='clip-4'>
    <polygon points="100,100 200,50 200,0 150,0"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id='clip-5'>
    <polygon points="100,100 200,100, 200,50"/>
    </clipPath>
    <image id="img" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
    xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/1/1000/800" />
  </defs>
<div class="container">
  <svg class="background" viewBox="0 0 200 100"></svg>

  <svg class="overlay vr-images1" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
    <use xlink:href="#img" class="vr-images1" clip-path="url(#clip-1)"/>
  </svg>
  <svg class="overlay vr-images2" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
    <use xlink:href="#img" class="vr-images2" clip-path="url(#clip-2)"/>
  </svg>
  <svg class="overlay vr-images3" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
    <use xlink:href="#img" clip-path="url(#clip-3)"/>
  </svg>
  <svg class="overlay vr-images4" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
    <use xlink:href="#img" clip-path="url(#clip-4)"/>
  </svg>
  <svg class="overlay vr-images5" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
    <use xlink:href="#img" clip-path="url(#clip-5)"/>
  </svg>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class='big'>
   <div class="white-bg"></div>
   <img src="https://i.ibb.co/rxX8VMq/left.png" class='default'>
   <img src="https://i.ibb.co/r77CrCC/topleft.png">
   <img src="https://i.ibb.co/CzRdRtp/top.png">
   <img src="https://i.ibb.co/L8cSs3p/topright.png">
   <img src="https://i.ibb.co/D1cjqfD/right.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56627894/7394871) от участника  [@Kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Я  обновил свой [предыдущий ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56576696/8620333), как показано ниже.
Я добавлю дополнительный элемент для изображений, которые вы меняете при наведении:

```css
.box {
  width: 450px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0; 
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/13/1000/800) center/cover;
 
}

.box>div:not(.big) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/118/1000/800);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  opacity: 0;
}


.box>div:nth-child(1) {
  clip-path: polygon(20% 0, 80% 0, 50% 100%);
}

.box>div:nth-child(2) {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 20% 0, 50% 100%, 0 40%);
}

.box>div:nth-child(3) {
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 80% 0, 50% 100%, 100% 40%);
}

.box>div:nth-child(4) {
  clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 50% 100%, 0 40%);
}

.box>div:nth-child(5) {
  clip-path: polygon(100% 100%, 50% 100%, 100% 40%);
}

.box>div:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.big {
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  left:calc(50% - 75px);
}  
.big img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .2s .1s ease-out;
}

.big .default {
  opacity: 1;
}

.box>div:nth-child(1):hover ~ .big > img:nth-child(1) {
  opacity:1;
  z-index:1;
}
.box>div:nth-child(2):hover ~ .big > img:nth-child(2) {
  opacity:1;
  z-index:1;
}
.box>div:nth-child(3):hover ~ .big > img:nth-child(3) {
  opacity:1;
  z-index:1;
}
.box>div:nth-child(4):hover ~ .big > img:nth-child(4) {
  opacity:1;
  z-index:1;
}
.box>div:nth-child(5):hover ~ .big > img:nth-child(5) {
  opacity:1;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class='big'>
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/CzRdRtp/top.png">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/r77CrCC/topleft.png">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/L8cSs3p/topright.png">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/rxX8VMq/left.png" class='default'>
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/D1cjqfD/right.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56627637/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>